# How to do data binding?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am trying to do some simple data binding in XAML but it is not working for me and I am not sure why.

I have this gridview

```
 <GridView Name="test2">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

I am trying to now bind. I tried to do it in XMAL(it crashes) and through C# code(Nothing happens)

In the code behind constructor I tried to do this

```
 public MyPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Test t = new Test
            {
                Header = "Header 1",
                Item = "Item 1",

            };

            List<Test> ts = new List<Test>();
            ts.Add(t);
            test2.DataContext = t;

        }
```

I also tried to pass it an collection as well.

As I said I could not get the XMAL way to do it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum to get this to work is to add the line:

```
test2.ItemsSource = ts;
```

But you've got few things that may cause you problems later.

1. The `DataContext` setting doesn't make much sense here, you're saying that you're going to make a **single** item the context for elements you're bind to a grid.  Typically, I'd say the DataContext would be a class that contains your collection of Tests - that would be the DataContext of your page, for instance, then you'd have

   <GridView Name="test2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}">

   where `Tests` is a property of whatever class you use as the `DataContext`. You want to make the DataContext the only thing you set in code, then everything else flows from the bindings.
2. Instead of `List`, you probably want to use `ObservableCollection`, so that the data binding engine will automatically be informed when items are added and removed from the collection.

Comment: Hi your first line works. I got a couple questions though are you saying you should make a Class as the DataContent so you can do more bindings to that single grid? Second question is what happens if I want a collection of Items do I make that ObservableCollection as well and how does my binding have to change?

Comment: yes to the first question - that class becomes your ViewModel, it's the DataContext for your page and then you can set ItemsSource in XAML not code. If you want the UI to reflect when items are added and removed from a list, like a list of Tests, then yes use ObservableCollection, it encapsulates code that notifies the binding ending of changes to the list.  For individual items, like the Test itself, you'll want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: When you say DataContext for a page. Are you saying I should hook the VM to the page not the grid control?

Comment: yes - it's not a hard and fast rule - a DataContext can be set anywhere, but as you're learning how it all works, that's the easiest approach.  There are a lot of great samples, including data binding, at http://dev.windows.com and the default Grid and Split templates will also demonstrate setting the DataContext on the page and binding to a collection off of that ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to bind the `ItemsSource` of your GridView to the collection.

Try following these steps:

1. Create a property on `MyPage`: `public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }`
2. Replace `test2.DataContext = t;` with `Tests = ts;`
3. In your XAML, add an `ItemsSource` property, like this:

   ```
   <GridView Name="test2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}">
   ```